# Regex multiple exclusions

Tags: regex, capture-group

I would like to make a regex that matches groups like `abbc`, where each letter is a different character.

- it should contain three capture groups
- all the capture groups should contain different characters
- the second one should be matched exactly twice

Example:

> bank (not matched, because the second and the third character is not the same)
>
> rook (matched)
>
> book (matched)
>
> poop (not matched, because the first and the last character is the same)

So far I have been trying something like this:

```
(.)(.(?!\1))\2(.(?!\1)(?!\2))
```

This however matches `poop` too. How do I correct this?

Comment: Regex might not be the correct tool for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your positioning of the lookaheads is a bit off, you can do it like

```
(.)(?!\1)(.)\2(?!\1|\2)(.)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/heBJar/1

You might need to apply anchors or word boundaries as needed. You should also consider using `[a-z]` or `[[:alpha:]]` or similar instead of the `.`.